# Mapping from multiple sources with inheritance with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper to map a pretty complex relation. I have the following code

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        VolvoCarSource volvoCarSource = new(name: "Volvo 740", wasMadeInSweden: true);
        ColorSource colorSource = new("Red");
        
        CarDestination simpleCarDestination = SimpleMap(volvoCarSource, colorSource);
        Print(simpleCarDestination);
        
        MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration = new (cfg => {
            // ???
        });
        mapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        IMapper mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        
        // CarDestination autoMapperCarDestination = mapper.Map<CarDestination>((volvoCarSource, colorSource));
        // Print(autoMapperCarDestination);
    }
    
    private static CarDestination SimpleMap(CarSource carSource, ColorSource colorSource)
    {
        if (carSource is VolvoCarSource volvoCarSource)
        {
            return new VolvoCarDestination(
                Name: volvoCarSource.Name,
                Color: colorSource.Name,
                WasMadeInSweden: volvoCarSource.WasMadeInSweden);
        }
        
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    
    private static void Print(CarDestination carDestination)
    {
        if (carDestination is VolvoCarDestination volvoCarDestination)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--- " + nameof(VolvoCarDestination) + " ---");
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(volvoCarDestination.Name) + ": " + volvoCarDestination.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(volvoCarDestination.Color) + ": " + volvoCarDestination.Color);
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(volvoCarDestination.WasMadeInSweden) + ": " + volvoCarDestination.WasMadeInSweden);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class CarSource
{
    public CarSource(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}

public class VolvoCarSource : CarSource
{
    public VolvoCarSource(string name, bool wasMadeInSweden)
        : base(name)
    {
        WasMadeInSweden = wasMadeInSweden;
    }
    
    public bool WasMadeInSweden { get; }
}

public record ColorSource(string Name);

public abstract record CarDestination(string Name, string Color);

public record VolvoCarDestination(string Name, string Color, bool WasMadeInSweden) : CarDestination(Name, Color);
```

I am trying to find a way using AutoMapper to map a `VolvoCarSource` together with a `ColorSource` into a `VolvoCarDestination`. Some objects are of type `record`. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to this or if it is even possible using AutoMapper. I have included a manual mapping which shows the expected output.

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BRCHI2)

How would I go about this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using AutoMapper with a two times map operation.

[.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uDYj51)

```cs
// Car
var car = new VolvoCarSource(name: "Volvo 740", wasMadeInSweden: true);

// Color
var color = new ColorSource("Red");

// Manual
// Mapped: Car + Color = Destination
var destination1 = SimpleMap(car, color);
Print(destination1);

// AutoMapper
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<VolvoCarSource, VolvoCarDestination>()
       .ConstructUsing((source, dest) => new VolvoCarDestination(source.Name, null!, source.WasMadeInSweden))
       .ForMember(m => m.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
       .ForMember(m => m.Color, o => o.Ignore())
       .ForMember(m => m.WasMadeInSweden, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.WasMadeInSweden));
    cfg.CreateMap<ColorSource, VolvoCarDestination>()
       .ConstructUsing((source, dest) => new VolvoCarDestination(null!, source.Name, false))
       .ForMember(m => m.Name, o => o.Ignore())
       .ForMember(m => m.Color, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
       .ForMember(m => m.WasMadeInSweden, o => o.Ignore());

    cfg.CreateMap<VolvoCarSource, CarDestination>()
       .ConstructUsing((source, dest) => new VolvoCarDestination(source.Name, null!, source.WasMadeInSweden))
       .ForMember(m => m.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
       .ForMember(m => m.Color, o => o.Ignore());
    cfg.CreateMap<VolvoCarDestination, CarDestination>()
       .ForMember(m => m.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
       .ForMember(m => m.Color, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Color));
});

config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

// Map / Create your CarDestination from the Car
var destination2 = mapper.Map<CarDestination>(car);
// Map / Merge you CarDestination from the Color
destination2 = mapper.Map<ColorSource, CarDestination>(color, destination2);
Print(destination2);
```

Output will then be two times the same:

[image]